# why am receiving the message pandas not defined even if I already import it?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, anaconda, analysis

hi am trying to do some data analysis to my excel sheet using anaconda JupyterLab so I imported pandas but when am trying to use it it's keep telling me name 'pod's not defined

I tried to look over the internet and I found all of the answers telling me that's I didn't import pandas

Comment: What do you mean `pod's` not defined? That's not pandas syntax. If you mean `pd` that's a common alias for pandas but you need to use `import pandas as pd` for that to work. Please share some code that doesn't work with the error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Import pandas as pd 

Df =pd.read_CSV(“WorldPopulation.csv”)
Df.head()

NameError: name ‘pd’ is not defined